# Will non standard-html-nodes be allowed to select by browsers?

Tags: css, html, angularjs

I've dug in to projects like angular a bit lately. In angular, you can create you own html-nodes like this:

```
      <gd-input-field label="Last Name" name="lastname" key="entry.544757237" required="true"></gd-input-field>
```

and give them properties etc.

In chrome it seems as though I can select the nodes to manipulate with css straight of the table, like this:

```
gd-input-field{
  display: none;
}
```

I understand that I'm breaking the specs here, but are there any problems with doing this, like lacking browser support or such?

Answer (score 1):

Old browsers, most notably **IE < 9** conform to the spec strictly and completely ignore tag names they don't understand. There is [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) which you can use to get around this limitation in old browsers

Evergreen browsers don't have this limitation, just choosing to let you use any tag names you want.

Comment: IF you need to support IE 8 and lower, sure. Otherwise you can use _"made up"_ HTML tags

Answer (score 0):

That's why I always prefer to use the "html valid" version when its possible:

- `data-ng` instead of `ng`.
- `replace: true` to your directive.
- `class=` to select elements via html.
- Directives restricted to attributes (and use the `data-my-directive`).